# Correct syntax for include css file?

Tags: css

Depending on where I look, I see different way to include css.

**Examples**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"                href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"             href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet"                                            href=""/>
```

Do they all do the same?

Is one of them the correct way?

Comment: Have a look through http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types. Specific times you may wish to define a media different than `all` is for example when you want to create printer friendly page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All are correct.
The `type` attribute is not required - it is just a hint for browsers but can be omitted.
The `media` attribute tells the browser when the CSS file should be used. For example, if you specify `media="print"` the CSS file will only get used when printing the page (try to print a Wikipedia page, for example).

Generally this variant is fine in most situations:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..."/>
```

Answer (score 4):

At minimum you need the `rel` and `href` attributes. The `type` attribute is often used, but not required.

The `media` attribute is used to target specific devices.

**For Example:**

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

tells the browser to apply the `print.css` file only if the user is trying to print the webpage.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer.  I thought it was only optional in HTML5, like the script type.  I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

They are all correct syntax.

Maybe this will help you : [css media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

The css will be picked depending on the media tag

- *all*

  Suitable for all devices.
- *braille*

  Intended for braille tactile feedback devices.
- *embossed*

  Intended for paged braille printers.
- *handheld*

  Intended for handheld devices (typically small screen, limited bandwidth).
- *print*

  Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode. Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
- *projection*

  Intended for projected presentations, for example projectors. Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
- *screen*

  Intended primarily for color computer screens.
- *speech*

  Intended for speech synthesizers. Note: CSS2 had a similar media type called 'aural' for this purpose. See the appendix on aural style sheets for details.
- *tty*

  Intended for media using a fixed-pitch character grid (such as teletypes, terminals, or portable devices with limited display capabilities). Authors should not use pixel units with the "tty" media type.
- *tv*

  Intended for television-type devices (low resolution, color, limited-scrollability screens, sound available).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the 4th is the least good as it does not declare the stylesheet file type, although it is optionally.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"                href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"             href=""/>
```

These three differ in the media, as you probably noticed. The media tells to which media the stylesheet should be applied to. See Section [7 (Media Types)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) of the CSS 2 standard.

I personally prefer this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("import1.css");
  @import url "import2.css";
</style>
```

For more information on `@import` have a look at [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatimport.htm) by about.com .

Answer (score 1):

Media attribuute specifies when the css file should be loaded

it should be working in all major browsers

**Valid values:** for media attribute

- **screen** - Computer screens (this is default)
- **tty** -    Teletypes and similar media using a fixed-pitch character grid
- **tv** - Television type devices (low resolution, limited scroll ability)
- **projection** - Projectors
- **handheld** -   Handheld devices (small screen, limited bandwidth)
- **print** -  Print preview mode/printed pages
- **braille** -    Braille feedback devices
- **aural** -  Speech synthesizers
- **all** -    Suitable for all devices

[reference w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LINK href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Reference:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html

Comment: Using CAPITALS for tags is a terrible idea and pretty bad advice.

Comment: ...and you should also always close the link tag, as the TS had done.

Comment: @DarkLightA that is not true, only for XHTML. XHTML is old and unawesome, HTML5 is new and awesome! :D

Comment: @WTP that is incorrect. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_link.asp, they use "<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>"

Comment: In any case it's terrible practise to not close tags. You never know how a browser can handle it.  @WTP

Comment: @Jamie Dixon, older versions of HTML didn't specify the capitalization of tags, browsers don't care. HTML5 specifically allows for case-insensitive tags. XHTML tried to force lower-case tags, but it never took off 100% because it really doesn't make a difference. The meaning of the data is the same.

Comment: @DarkLightA, HTML allows for tags like `link` to not need a closing tag or the closing `/`. XHTML encouraged a much more strict version of HTML, but most people could never quite get it implemented 100% (no using `embed`, always have `alt` on `img` elements etc). With HTML5 taking off, it really doesn't matter that much anymore.

Comment: @DarkLightA, w3schools is not affiliated with the [w3c](http://w3c.org). If you haven't seen it already, please review http://w3fools.com/. Browsers will handle `link` elements just fine, even IE is good about closing stand-alone tags.

Comment: But the OP used `/>` in the question. Maybe she was using XHTML.

Comment: @DarkLightA read the HTML 5 specification, not W3Schools. Also see [this](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @Jamie Dixon I copied the line from w3.org style sheets introduction page, and i did put the reference link as well. Care to see?

Comment: I know. I still think it's terrible advice even coming from the W3C.